# Can't connect to socket.io server with android client

Tags: java, android, ios, node.js, sockets

For my NodeJS server code, I'm using the [chat server code](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js) that is linked to in the [socket io android tutorial](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/).

I'm following the tutorial above to a tee in my android project.

`build.gradle`:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");
            Log.e("CONNECTED", "SUCCESS");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR CONNECTING");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.emit("message", "message");
    }
}
```

When I compile this, no matter what I put as the URL for `IO.socket(<url>)`, it always logs out that it connected. When I load the app, it's supposed to emit `message` and send `"message"`, but I never get it on the server. I never even get a "user connected" log in my server log, which I have setup to log out anytime a something connects to it.

Just to test to make sure my server code isn't faulty, I created a client project in NodeJS:

`client.js`:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log("connected")
});
```

And it and the server both log out 'connected' when I run it. So something is wrong with the java code.... I can't figure it out.

Comment: notice that mSocket = IO.socket("http://chatserver:3000") just defines the object and the actual connection occurs on mSocket.connect() line. So I think your log code  Log.e("CONNECTED", "SUCCESS") is just misleading. put the try/catch on connect and see what comes up.